# API for managing the Users in the Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

Admin manages the Users from Admin google page (admin.google.com) and I are curious whether there is any API document like Rest API's available. Purpose: Admin can manage the users (like add user, delete user, fetch users list) from Postman using this Rest API's.

Answer (score 1):

You can use G Suite Admin SDK's [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users) to manage users and groups as you intend. For a precise description of each resource representation, have a look at the API reference, for example [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users) for the User resource.